# How to visualize current CPU usage of a pod with Grafana

Tags: monitoring, kubernetes, cpu-usage, grafana, prometheus

Is there a way to visualize **current** CPU usage of a pod in a K8S cluster?

I tried different Prometheus metrics like `namespace_pod_name_container_name:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate` and other similar ones, but I always get average value for the last 5 minutes, so I have "stairs" on my graphs even if workload raises abruptly (please, see the [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mq2zhgsr9vznny1/Screenshot%202019-09-17%2018.29.02.png?dl=0)).

At the same time, `kubectl top pod` shows more precise values, so when I raise workload to 100%, it starts showing 100% utilization in a few seconds.

Is there a way to provide these values to Grafana?

Thanks!

Comment: `namespace_pod_name_container_name:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate` is a prometheus recording rule, for which there is a corresponding query, which you can find by seeing the recording rules in Prometheus; The recording rule most likely has an interval set for 5m with [5m]; Hence the average was for 5minutes

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you can try the query below:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name)
```

This would track the CPU usage of each of the pods and the results would be shown in 1 minute rate. Of course you can adjust the `[1m]` parameter (and others) as you need.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

in my case only sum works but when I add rate with [15m] then it gives error on the by (pod)

Did you miss the sum_rate in your solution? In my case I use sum_irate

sum(   node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{cluster="$cluster", namespace="seet"}
( * = multiply symbol)    on(namespace,pod)
group_left(workload, workload_type) namespace_workload_pod:kube_pod_owner:relabel{cluster="$cluster", namespace="seet", workload="seetbackend", workload_type="deployment"}
) by (pod)